# Is it safe to shut down my PC right after intensive CPU/GPU load?

Tags: sleep, shutdown, cooling, temperature

Is it a good idea to shut down or put to sleep my PC seconds after some very heavy processing load on the CPU or GPU?

I'm asking this because i'm not sure if the cooling system has enough time to cool the components down to an acceptable temperature before the shut down; that would mean that the components might even be damaged or have their lifespan significantly reduced due to insufficient cooling.

Should i worry about this or does the hardware is smart enough not to shut down the cooling before it reaches an acceptable temperature?

Comment: I vote to let it cool down before shutdown.

Comment: Why would you think a faster change in temperature would be better than a slower one? That seems backwards to me.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Isn't this what coolers already do?

Comment: @GabrielS. Not really. Because while a good cooler will cool the CPU faster, it will also cool it from a temperature that's not so high. But a smart cooler that can adjust fan speed to both keep the peak temperature as low as possible and avoid cooling the CPU too rapidly is best. But the most important factor for both CPU life and performance is keeping the peak temperature as low as possible.

Comment: There is a temperature range in which the chip will operate properly.  When powered off, you aren't worried about operation.  Temperatures that can physically damage a powered off chip are much higher.  The heat comes from the electrical operation of the chip.  You're removing that heat as it's produced.  When you remove power, you aren't adding any new heat, and the silicon wafer inside can't get hotter than it was when powered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to shut down or put to sleep my PC seconds after
>   some very heavy processing load on the CPU or GPU?

It is neither a bad idea or a good idea.  A PC is designed to be turned off, put to sleep, and to be left on.  It being used at 100% load or 0% load makes no difference, it is designed to be used, any failures will not be linked to the type of work it does.

> I'm asking this because i'm not sure if the cooling system has enough
>   time to cool the components down to an acceptable temperature before
>   the shut down; that would mean that the components might even be
>   damaged or have their lifespan significantly reduced due to
>   insufficient cooling.

If electricity is being ran through a circuit, and the temperature of the corespondents are within their specification, then having no electricity and the temperature still being within the specifications makes no difference.  Your PC will cool itself off faster, without being turned on, for obvious reasons.  I have left my last 4 computers, spanning over 20 years, turned on 24/7/365.

If the system is cooled enough to keep the system stable for 12 hours a day then its stable enough to be ran 24/7/365.

> Should i worry about this or does the hardware is smart enough not to
>   shut down the cooling before it reaches an acceptable temperature?

There is nothing to worry about.  The cooling system in a general sense does not care if the system is at 100% load or 50% load it will continue to cool the system no matter what.

*You do understand, the hardware is not smart enough to do anything it was not designed to do, right?*

Comment: So, for instance, if my CPU is at 80 Celsius degrees and i suddenly shut down the PC, will the cooling system prevent shutdown until the temperature is lowered significantly? If it doesn't, then it would mean the CPU stays at those higher temps for (much) longer than if i let the cooling system lower it first instead of shutting the PC down. Could this be a problem?

Comment: If your CPU is running at 80 degrees Celsius then, the moment it reaches the appropriate power state (G3 or S5), your machine will be turned off.  Once machine is turned off, it does not matter what the temperature is at, because it will only become cooler (only the electricity in the circuit raises the temperature of the components).

Comment: @GabrielS. Cooling more slowly would mean slightly *less* wear on the CPU and GPU. The faster they change temperature, the worse.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't have to worry about the cooling, the manufacturer has build the CPU, GPU and the Computer so that there no damage can be caused throught to temperature. For example Intel CPUs are made to stand temperatures
amounting to up to 100°C. And even if the performeance is so high that it make heating trouble, the CPU will automatically clock down.

Also to mention is that the CPU gets enought cooled down during the shutdown process. Only if you turn off your computer suddenly I'm not really sure that the CPU gets enough cooled down.

There is also protective mechanism build in the chips cooling down automatically when the max. Temp. gets exceeded. The OS or rather the drivers software on the computer that the max. Temp. doesn't gets overstepped. In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8srUp_lSXE) video you can see the build-in protective mechanism in action. When the guy took off the fan while the cpu is running, the cpu immediately turn-off to get no damage and cools down very fast. Sorry that the video is only in german!

Only if you have manipulated your cooler or the protective mechanism in the chip for example throught a [cool controlling software](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) or with the BIOS (look picture below). Then you have to keep the performance and the temperature in view. But it has not only negative aspects. When you control the cooling manualy you can also increase the fan speed when the system it didn't done automaticaly.

### [image]

---

If you have frequent cooling problems you should think about to upgrade your cooling system with [water cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cooling#Computer_types). There are also [watercooled graphic cards](http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news2/PNY-Debuts-Water-Cooled-XLR8-GTX-580-Graphics-Card-2.jpg) for the GPU.

---

My personal recommend for your question is:

> When you normal shutdown the computer (no matter how high the temperature or the utilization was), there will not get any serious damage. Optimal would be before you shutdown your pc to close all unimportant task and let the computer cooling down for a few minutes before you go to sleep mode or shutdown. Setting the fan speed permanently or during heavy process to maxium via cool control software can be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I cool mine down before sending it to sleep or shutdown. It seems it would be just like a car and you would get heat soak, without any cooling system running it gets hotter even if its off. Cooling down anything slowly is a good idea, just like turbochargers on vehicles.

Comment: Relating your personal practice and assumptions isn't really an authoritative answer.  This would be better if you cite research on which your practice is based.

Answer (score 0):

My job is a Maintenance Engineer in semi-conductor company. heating or cooling slowly doesn't matter. ALL IC and other components inside your cpu undergoes several baking and cooling for about 180 degrees celsius and -180 degrees celcius.
so,all the components are made of special materials that can withstand over heating or super cooling. so just relax.

Comment: I don't think that's how it works though. You can't just expect components which are strong and resistant on their own to be strong and resistant in any combination. That's just a wild claim to make, especially coming from an allegedly experienced professional from the field (if you excuse my healthy skepticism).